# Slide layout or View

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-fragments

There is a game called [STRATA](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.graveck.stratapremium&hl=en) in google play.

I want to implement functionality of layout like strata has. See Image below.

[image]

- Functionality of strata game is when user press "?" button as shown above another layout slide in and current slide out of the screen.
- **What i want to achieve is : On button press another layout slide in from top and current goes out, But both layout should partially visible to user.**
- How can i achieve this kind of functionality? Give me any basic idea from where i can start. 
  Thank you.

Comment: visit this link : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: This is not what i was looking for.

Comment: uhhh animations and overridePendingTransition()? Anyways let me check this app.

Comment: i thought that but still has a doubt.. that's why i asked here..

Comment: Opps, checked it out. here's my idea. create a LinearLayout to contain the menu above then just set the visibility into gone. That will not  occupy any space on your (let's say) game layout screen. Then on tap of the button just set the visibility to visible then apply animation to slide. Well I guess that's the most simple action.

Comment: yeah .. i have tried this .. got some success.. Thnx